# How can I get Heroku's database information in a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rake

I created a rails app that is hosted on Heroku. Now I want to upload a ruby script that will populate my database.
This script already exists and is using

```
PGconn.connect( :hostaddr=>"127.0.0.1", :port=>5432, :dbname=>"myDB", :user=>"MyUser", :password=>'MyPass');
```

This will obviously not work on Heroku.

I tried to get it using:

```
Rails.configuration.database_configuration
```

But I get

> uninitialized constant Rails

How can I get the information so I can connect to my Heroku DB? Is there any way to make the same code wotk both on my localhost and on Heroku? 
(ps: I am using foreman and the .ENV file, if it helps)

Edit:
The solution I took:

```
require 'yaml'
require 'erb'    
config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.join("config","database.yml"))).result)
```

In config I have all the information I need to perform the DB access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you not just access `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` and break it up into the constituent parts? To see how this is done, if you do `heroku run bash` and do `cat config\database.yml` you will see how Heroku does this itself.

To ensure that locally it works as well if you execute via `foreman run <Scriptname>` then it will be executed and the contents of your .env will be loaded.

Comment: I was looking at the database.yml file from Heroku. Can't I just access the database.yml file and get the information? It would be already parsed

Comment: This was not exactly the approach I took, but marking as answer because it led me to my solution. I used config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(File.join("config","database.yml"))).result) (require 'yaml' and 'erb'), there I have the informatin already parsed. Thanks for the help!